# Crystal Reports - Several Group Levels - Improve Efficiency

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've had to make some modifications to one of our reports that is comprised of ~30 sub-reports to change it from being ~4 group levels to now having ~18 group levels.  It seems like it's been hit with major processing degradation.  I've added group suppression as the only group levels I care about are: 1 (used to break out the data coming back into sections so the database doesn't have to be requeried multiple times thus eliminating extra database hits and extra sub-reports), 6-11 (divisional/regional/etc. data), and 18 (base level, by person).

The levels in between those I need may be needed in the future so they've been accounted for now, but since it's had such a negative impact on the performance I'd like to disable them.  Right now they're suppressed but they're obviously still being processed which is killing the performance.

How can I restore the efficency without losing all the work I've done?

Answer (score 1):

If a section containing a subreport is suppressed- the subreport shouldn't be executed and hence the query not executed.

From the report menu, select performance information and you will get a breakdown of what is taking the time.

If this isn't self explanatory- give us some more information and we should be able to help.

Comment: The sections in the sub-report are suppressed. There are 40 sub-reports that each bring back ~1500 records. Each sub-report is using a stored proc to run and the stored procs take < 7 seconds to run. When I try to open the results of the report in InfoView after it finally completes (takes about 20 minutes to run) it takes over 5 minutes to open.  Prior to this the report took 5-8 minutes to run and opened within 20 seconds.

Comment: Hang on. You're saying that the main report sections containing the subreports, and the subreports themselves are NOT suppressed. But the sectinos WITHIN the subreports are suppressed? This is your problem. A subreport will still run even if all of it's sections are suppressed.

Comment: Yes, there is a plethora of information being reported as a one stop shop for the reporting instead of having to look at 40 different reports it's been consolidated into one report.  It should run each subreport, but in each subreport I only need a handful of the grouping sections to be processed.  Even though they are suppressed it is still taking far too long for the report to render.

Comment: Are you sure that the sub reports can't be run on demand?  That may increase the speed of the report significantly.